# Compare Date String in Android

Tags: android, string, date

I have two strings, the first one contains an actual date, and the second one contains a date format.

I want to compare both the strings. Here is my code:

for current date

```
Date referenceDate = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    c.setTime(referenceDate); 
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -30);
    //c.getTime();

    //System.out.println("Date class"+c.getTime());

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    currentDateandTime = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println("Simple Date Format "+currentDateandTime);
```

and 2nd date code is here

```
private void setDate() {


    try {
        sbMain = obj.get("date_of_report").toString().split(" ");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }

    String[] sb = sbMain[0].split("-");

    String[] sb2 = sbMain[1].split(":");

    System.out.println("Alert Time : " + sb[0] + " " + sb[1] + " " + sb[2] + " " + sb2[0] + ":" + sb2[1] + ":" + sb2[2]);

}
```

Comment: hello gaurav, have you looked at date4j library. It  helps your in comparing dates efficiently.

Comment: no no i want to compare two strings only

Comment: then you may use regex, and match to see if your date matches some format/expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have all the components of your second date, e.g Day,time,Month and Year then use the same Calendar class to obtain date object by setting correct time and date components you retrieved, now you have two valid instances of your dates, get the values of both in Millis, and perform whatever comparision you want.